detect duplicated values in golang and leveldb
I need an algorithm that can fully check a leveldb database and remove duplicate values.
But the problem is that this database is too big to fit in RAM.
In my opinion, similar algorithms like external sorting can be inspired, but I don't know how
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
